# sending emails on a loop using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, email, smtplib

I am trying to use a for-loop to send an email to multiple recipients, if "<>" is found in the subject or body, it is replaced dynamically with the recipients name.

I am looping over a dictionary of recipients in the form `{"name": "email"}`

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send(recipients, subject, message):
    for name, email in recipients.items():
        edited_subject = subject.replace("<>", name)
        edited_message = message.replace("<>", name)

        mail = MIMEMultipart()
        mail['from'] = 'Tomas'
        mail['to'] = email
        mail['subject'] = edited_subject
        mail.attach(MIMEText(edited_message, "plain"))

        with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.starttls()
            smtp.login(username, password)
            smtp.send_message(mail)
```

the loop seems to only sends to the first recipient.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add a **sleep(60)** in the end! That fixed it for me. Don't forget to import **time** module at the top.
Explanation: Some email providers such as free ones like gmail require a delay as they don't allow emails to be send within seconds just as in a loop. DONT Forget to create the loop after creation of smtp.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import time


def send(recipients, subject, message):
    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login(username, password)
        for name, email in recipients.items():
            edited_subject = subject.replace("<>", name)
            edited_message = message.replace("<>", name)

            mail = MIMEMultipart()
            mail['from'] = 'Tomas'
            mail['to'] = email
            mail['subject'] = edited_subject
            mail.attach(MIMEText(edited_message, "plain"))
            smtp.send_message(mail)
            time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

The with statement ensures proper acquisition and release of resources. Instead of creating a new smtp every loop, try creating it once and then loop inside the context:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send(recipients, subject, message):
    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login(username, password)
        for name, email in recipients.items():
            edited_subject = subject.replace("<>", name)
            edited_message = message.replace("<>", name)

            mail = MIMEMultipart()
            mail['from'] = 'Tomas'
            mail['to'] = email
            mail['subject'] = edited_subject
            mail.attach(MIMEText(edited_message, "plain"))
            smtp.send_message(mail)
```